# What is the right way to access images in Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I have some images under `src/main/webapp/dist/img`

[image]

I am able to access these files from my html templates, using relative paths:

```
        <img src="../../../dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
```

If I move the file to a subfolder, I have to update all paths.

What is the correct way to access images in a JHipster generated application?

Comment: place the images in content folder

Comment: Does it solve the problem >> "If I move the file to a subfolder, I have to update all paths"

Comment: dist folder will be created when you build. if you clean your project then this folder gets removed.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But this isn't an answer to my question.

Comment: You need to update all paths, better to have them in content folder, it may not work in prod profile. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it into the `content` folder and you can reference like this:

```
<img src="/content/avatar.png" />
```